# Jquery Mobile problem with AJAX updates

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having a very weird problem with radio buttons in JQuery Mobile. I'm populating some radiobuttons with ajax. When I do it the first time it's ok, but any subsequent loads seem to cause problems with the display - each checkbox is displayed separately rather than on a single list.

```
function getWords() {

    var gig_id = $('#gigs').val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: Nnn.serverLocation+'/words?gigid='+ gig_id,
        success: function(data) {   
            Nnn.words =  eval('(' + data + ')');  
            displayWords();
        }
    });
}

function displayWords() {
    $('#word_container').html('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="words"></fieldset>');

    $('#words').html("<legend>It's:</legend>");
    $.each(Nnn.words, function(key, value) { 
        $('#words').append('<label for="'+value.Word+'" >'+value.Word+'</label><input type="radio" value="'+value.Word+'" id="'+value.Word+'" name="radio-choice-1" />');           
    });

    $('#words input').checkboxradio();

    $('body').page();
}
```

The HTML looks like

```
<div id='all' data-role="page">

    <div data-role="content">


    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id='word_container'>


        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id='words'>


        </fieldset>
     </div> 
      </div>
```

It's driving me crazy!

Comment: I actually have a similar problem with buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the proper load/display of CSS in the page. If you reload the page using Ajax, you can not use HTML5 data-* attributes. For example, button control in jQueryMobile is represented like this:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```

If you use the same markup in the ajax call, it won't be displayed properly. What you have to do is, Firefox/Chrome/Opera->Right Click->Inspect Element and use the markup shown there. So, the proper markup for the button control would be:

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-hover-c" data-role="button" href="index.html" data-theme="c">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Link button</span>
  </span>
</a>
```