# jQuery Mobile: Styling content loaded through AJAX

Tags: jquery-mobile

On a particular jQuery Mobile page I am loading content through an AJAX post. I am then replacing some content in the DOM with the returned HTML. 
The returned HTML contains form elements, which I would like jQM to style.

This used to work in beta 1:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.worked) {
                    voucher_area.fadeOut(function () {
                        $(this).html(response.html).children().page();
                        $(this).fadeIn();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Notify.showMessage("Could not update your call with voucher information: " + response.message, "error");
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function () {
                Notify.showMessage("Fatal Error.");
            }
        });
```

The call to page on the content would style the content.
However in the latest version this no longer seems to work.

Is there a correct way to style loaded content?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this is the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346424/jquery-mobile-problem-with-ajax-updates/6548047#6548047

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to style content directly using something like: $(this).css({'padding':'5px'}) using the styles of your choice.

Alternatively, you should be able to define the appropriate styles in an external css file as well.

Comment: jQuery mobile applies a multitude of css and javascript events to elements to 'mobilize' them. It would be tedious to try and do this by hand, to say the least. There used to be a function that would effectively do this for you, which seems to have broken, or changed the way it works in the latest build.